# ASDoc compiling error in Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, asdoc

I can't seem to figure out why i continue getting this error every-time I try to compile ASDoc in Flash Builder 4.

I did succeed in ASDoc creating a asdoc-output folder but it is incomplete. There is only toplevel.xml and a tempdita folder that show up.

This is the error that shows up on my Console

```
Error at xsl:choose on line 46 of processHTML.xslt:
  java.io.FileNotFoundException:
  /Users/NEWYORK/abritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/ATE_Shell/asdoc-output/index.tmp (No such
  file or directory)
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/Users/NEWYORK%5Cabritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/ATE_Shell/asdoc-output/tempdita/processHTML.xslt#25)
     processing /html
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

Line 46 is in ProcessHTML.xslt is the initial `<xsl:choose>` in the element bellow.

```
<xsl:template match="html">
<xsl:copy-of select="$noLiveDocs"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test=".//frameset">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$frameDocType"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$docType"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$isLiveDocs"/>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$markOfTheWeb"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:element name="html">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$copyrightComment"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I went to External Tool Configuration and added the location of asdoc

```
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4/sdks/flex_sdk_4.1/bin/asdoc
```

then i added my Working Directory

```
${workspace_loc:/ATE_Shell}
```

And lastly I inserted all my arguments

```
-lenient
-source-path src -doc-sources src
-external-library-path=/Users/NEWYORK\abritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/ActivityToolkitLib/bin/ActivityToolkitLib.swc
-external-library-path=/Users/NEWYORK\abritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/ATE_Template/bin/ATE_Template.swc
-external-library-path=/Users/NEWYORK\abritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/AssesmentCommunicationLib/bin/AssesmentCommunicationLib.swc
-external-library-path=/Users/NEWYORK\abritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/BFW_UI/bin/BFW_UI.swc
-external-library-path=/Users/NEWYORK\abritez/Documents/workspaces/ate/DiagnosticReporter/bin/DiagnosticReporter.swc
```

UPDATE:
I ended up rolling back to 3.5 and did a test application with only one method to document and got this error.

My method

```
package com.test
{
import mx.containers.Canvas;


public class Grouptest extends Canvas
{
    public function Grouptest()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     *  Hello
     * 
     * @param   value   Some string
     * */

    public function set testMe(value:String):void
    {
        trace("value " + value)
    }
}
}
```

My Error

```
Loading configuration file /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4/sdks/3.5.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml Adobe ASDoc 
Version 3.5.0 build 12683 
Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved. 

Error: '' is not a directory 
Use 'asdoc -help' for information about using the command line
```

Any help or point to the right direction would be greatly appriciated. I've gotten ASDoc running in the past so I am sure I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Good luck. I've lost at least a couple of man-weeks on AS-doc related shenanigans

Answer (score 2):

ASDoc is notoriously bad at reporting errors and giving red herrings.

The following was suitable for Flex 3. I assume that it is still appropriate for Flex 4.

Main thing to remember is that ASDoc only does one pass, unlike the compiler which does (at least) two. This exposes issues that the Compiler hides for you, classically if you declare something as bindable but don't make the class an IEventDispatcher, the compiler cheats for you on the first pass, but ASDoc will simply fail.

Another common issue is file not founds when using tags like @see. If you've named the path wrong, ASDoc used to fall over and not generate.

Third most common problem in my experience is malformed html tags. Forgetting to add the

or adding HTML tags into ASDoc tags which don't accept them.

Sadly, because ASDoc is *SO* bad at reporting these errors and doesn't gracefully handle mistakes, its a royal nightmare to find where the problem is without going over the code line by line...

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I went though all my code and found several instance that may have caused a problem, however no luck.

Comment: Also I ended up rolling back to 3.5 and did a test application with only one method to document and got this error. 
Loading configuration file /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4/sdks/3.5.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml
Adobe ASDoc 
Version 3.5.0 build 12683
Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.

Error: '' is not a directory

Use 'asdoc -help' for information about using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're dealing with 4, but I ran into the same issue with 3.5 so the following may apply:

This is happening because the asdocs folder, and more importantly asdocs/templates folder wasn't included in the 3.5 distribution of the Flex SDK.  Simply copy asdocs from 3.4 or another 3.x sdk and it'll work.

http://michael.omnicypher.com/2011/05/flex-35-and-using-asdocs.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I finally found [a random post about this same issue](http://blog.ms-net.co.uk/?p=14) and that fixed it for me.

> Another time black hole with asdoc generation
>
> [asdoc] [Fatal Error]
>   toplevel.xml:90:2: The content of
>   elements must consist of well-formed
>   character data or markup.
>
> [asdoc] Error: Could not create
>   toplevel.xml: The content of elements
>   must consist of well-formed character
>   data or markup.
>
> This one is caused by a random
>   character in your asdoc comments that
>   the parser doesn’t like. In my case a
>   couple of < or > along with a @.